# WPF DataGrid disabling rows while still able to add

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WDF Datagrid, when a row is brought back from the database, I want to stop the user from editing the row, however, I still want the user to be able to add new rows and edit rows that havent been saved to the database yet.

Is there a way I can do this?

I have looked at isReadOnly property but assigning that to true, will obviously disable all rows and will stop the user adding more rows!

Thanks

XAML Code

```
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="True" 
              Name="dace"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
              Height="183" 
              Margin="45,115,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding CollectionItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
              Width="530"
              InitializingNewItem="DataGrid_InitializingNewItem" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom RowStyle:

```
            <DataGrid>
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEdited}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            </DataGrid>
```

Obviously, you need to create a "frame" class, with your true Class like Content and a boolean value "IsEdited" who are set at false in the begin and a true after editing the row.

Comment: Thank you Gaston, I was thinking of using the IsEdit as a converter? is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. The solution for me was to cancel the editing for any undesired row. 
[DataGrid.BeginningEdit Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.beginningedit?view=netcore-3.1)

```
<DataGrid BeginningEdit="DataGrid_BeginningEdit" />

private void DataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow dgr = e.Row;
        Question question = dgr.Item as Question;
        if (someCondition)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```